# Better codes to develop

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

DIFFERENCES

```
  select CE1.CLASS_ID, 
         CE1.LOCATION_ID,
         count(case CE1.FORMAT_ID  when 5 then 1 end) as LIVE,
         count(case CE1.FORMAT_ID  when 14 then 1 end) as LB,
         count(case CE1.FORMAT_ID  when 15 then 1 end) as WEB,
         SUM(DECODE (CE1.ROLE_ID,5,1,0)) FACULTY,
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.ROLE_ID ,2,1,0)) MODERATOR,
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.ROLE_ID ,3,1,0)) PANELIST,  
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.ROLE_ID,4,1,0)) PRESENTER,
         COUNT(CE1.USER_ID) TOT 
    from C_EDUCATION1 CE1 
GROUP BY CE1.LOCATION_ID, CE1.CLASS_ID
```

We are developing existing system and we found mixed use COUNT and DECODE. 
If we understand correctly, we could convert to following codes.

```
  select CE1.CLASS_ID,  
         CE1.LOCATION_ID, 
         SUM(DECODE (CE1.FORMAT_ID ,5,1,0)) LIVE,
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.FORMAT_ID ,14,1,0)) LB, 
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.FORMAT_ID,15,1,0)) WEB,
         SUM(DECODE (CE1.ROLE_ID,5,1,0)) FACULTY,
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.ROLE_ID ,2,1,0)) MODERATOR,
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.ROLE_ID ,3,1,0)) PANELIST,  
         SUM(DECODE  (CE1.ROLE_ID,4,1,0)) PRESENTER,
         COUNT(CE1.USER_ID) TOT 
    from C_EDUCATION1 CE1 
GROUP BY CE1.LOCATION_ID, CE1.CLASS_ID
```

OR 
All COUNT

We are wondering differences in performance, or others issues.
Is it better way exist?

Comment: I'm not aware of performance differences between using CASE vs DECODE, but CASE is ANSI so the query would be more portable if DECODE was swapped out for CASE.  I would consider DECODE to be deprecated, but it will never go away for sake of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Your CASE variants should include an ELSE clause for clarity.  I suppose the default is NULL, which then isn't counted, but for systematic, consistent coding, use SUM in all versions - and then you most definitely need an ELSE clause.

Answer (score 4):

There will be no performance difference between the two.

Personally, I would tend to prefer a CASE-based solution.  CASE is ANSI standard rather than an Oracle-specific function.  Developers that are coming from other database platforms will probably have to look up the semantics of the DECODE statement. CASE is also relatively obvious to developers regardless of the language they're familiar with.  Virtually every language has a CASE statement so any developer should be able to quickly see what you're doing.

That being said, I would tend to advocate something like

```
SELECT ce1.class_id,
       ce1.location_id,
       SUM( CASE WHEN format_pkg.is_live( format_id ) = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) live,
       SUM( CASE WHEN format_pkg.is_lb(   format_id ) = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) lb,
       ...
```

This uses the CASE from the first query, the SUM from the second, and adds some function calls to determine what type of format/ role is being discussed.  This prevents you from having to hard-code the FORMAT_ID/ ROLE_ID values all over the place.  And using SUM rather than COUNT is a bit clearer since it's probably not immediately obvious to a developer that COUNT excludes the NULL values.